# C++ - Queue pop not working corrrectly using using for() loop

Tags: for-loop, visual-c++, while-loop, queue

While writing a simple code using STL queue and `for` loop, I faced a problem. My procedure is simple: take a number as a string, convert them into queue elements and show them.

My code is below :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<string>
//#include<cctype>
using namespace std;

//int to_words(int i);
//int to_words_one(queue<int> &q);

int main()
{
queue<int> q;
string s;
cout << "Enter a number not more than 12 digits : ";
getline(cin, s, '\n');
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    if (!isdigit(s[i]))
    {
        cout << "Not a valid number." << endl;
        s.clear();          
        break;
    }
}
if(s.size() > 0)
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
      q.push(s[i] - '0');

while (!q.empty())
{
    cout << q.front();
    q.pop();
}
system("PAUSE");
}
```

It works fine. No problem. But instead of `while(!q.empty())`, if I use

```
for(int j=0;j < q.size(); j++)
{
   cout << q.front();
   q.pop();
}
```

It doesn't work properly! It just shows and pops some first elements , and NOT ALL elements of the queue and prompts for `Press any key to continue`. Please tell me why is this happening? Shouldn't `while(!q.empty())` and and that `for()` loop work similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `q.size()` decreases after each `q.pop()` and is evaluated in each iteration of the for loop. For instance, let's say you had 6 elements in your queue, the for loop state in subsequent iterations will be as below:

- i = 0, q.size() = 6,
- i = 1, q.size() = 5,
- i = 2, q.size() = 4,
- i = 3, q.size() = 3,

so only first 3 elements would be printed. If you want to use a for loop, save `q.size()` to a variable before the first iteration, like this:

```
int q_size = q.size();
for (int i = 0; i < q_size; i++) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By calling `queue::pop` size of queue is decremented, so suppose you entered 8 digits, in first iteration of for loop `q.size()` returns 8, then you compare `j < 8` it is true and `j` is incremented and size of queue is decremented. In the next iteration of loop for you compare `j < 7`, where `j` is 1. Do 2-th, 3-th iterations... After 4-th iterations `j` counter has value 4, and size of queue is 4 too, so condition `j < 4` returns false, and only 4 digits were printed.